# Calculus inequality for proportions

Tags: calculus

Given that $\sum_{i = 1}^{K}p_{i} = 1$, want to show that,

If $p_{u}\neq\frac{1}{K}$ then there exist some $p_{i}$ and $p_{j}$ such that $p_{i}+p_{j}<\frac{2}{K}$.

Comment: Wrong for $K=2$. Short proof for $K>2$ : Let's imagine that there is one $p_u > 1/K$. Then there must be at least one $p_i < 1/K$ to compensate (else the sum would be larger than one). If there is only one such number, we take $p_i < 1/K$ and $p_j = 1/K$. If there are two such numbers, there exists $p_j < 1/K$, and its done.

Comment: Yes they are positive. Thanks harry.